# Merging two *.pdf file in one in excel

Tags: excel, cmd, vba

I have list of numbers in a column, i want to merge them into one file name where prefix is same.

For Example: 12345678_1.pdf 12345678_2.pdf

I want it save to a specific folder.

Can you please help me with a VBA code or cmd code were I can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The main procedure can be something like:

```
Sub MergeAll()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 9999 Step 2
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For
        MergePDF "E:\0\A\MergePdf\", Cells(i, 1).Value, Cells(i + 1, 1).Value, Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, Len(Cells(i, 1).Value) - 5) & ".pdf"
    Next
End Sub
```

and the called procedure to merge it's:

```
Sub MergePDF(PathF, strExportFile1, strExportFile2, strExportFileX As String)
' Reference Necessary: Adobe Acrobat xx Type Library
 'Relies on the Adobe Acrobat 6.0 Type Library
 Dim objCAcroPDDocDestination As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
 Dim objCAcroPDDocSource As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

 'Initialize the objects
 Set objCAcroPDDocDestination = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
 Set objCAcroPDDocSource = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

 'Open Destination, all other documents will be added to this and saved with
 'a new filename
 objCAcroPDDocDestination.Open (PathF & strExportFile1)

 objCAcroPDDocSource.Open (PathF & strExportFile2)
 If objCAcroPDDocDestination.InsertPages(objCAcroPDDocDestination.GetNumPages - 1, objCAcroPDDocSource, 0, objCAcroPDDocSource.GetNumPages, 0) Then
     Debug.Print "Documents Merged!"
 Else
     Debug.Print "Document NOT Merged!"
 End If
 objCAcroPDDocSource.Close

 objCAcroPDDocDestination.Save 1, PathF & strExportFileX
 objCAcroPDDocDestination.Close
 Set objCAcroPDDocSource = Nothing
 Set objCAcroPDDocDestination = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code need to have installed & referenced:

```
Adobe Acrobat xx Type Library
```